# What is the term for assigning multiple IP addresses to single NIC within the same network?

Tags: bridge, nic

I've been looking for the term used to define the process of assigning multiple IP addresses to single IP address. A similar term that I found so far is [Multihoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming#Host_multihoming) but, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. According to Wikipedia

> **Multihoming** is the practice of connecting a host or a computer network
>   to more than one network. This can be done in order to increase
>   reliability or performance, or to reduce cost.

In the variant of multihoming which applies to single host, namely Host multihoming, **a single host would get multiple IP addresses belonging to different networks** whereas what I'm looking for is the process where **one NIC gets multiple IP address from the same network**. It's a subtle difference. An example of what I'm looking for is a virtualbox instance configured in "bridged network" mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is  called [IP aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing).

Note:  This is different from a NIC set into bridged mode. In this mode, the userspace of the host OS doesn't see the virtual NICs and can't use the IP addresses bound to them to communicate.